# Multiple Azure/ADFS/OpenConnect/oAuth Identity Framework options on single site

Tags: oauth, asp.net-identity, openid, azure-active-directory, adfs

I have a Angular site that is multi-tenant. When they login they're linked to a specific organization that we keep track of using Web Api.

We're using the excellent articles written here: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/ as our starting point to get everything going with webapi and angular for handling the identity framework through Web Api with Angular and that works well.

We have the ability to login as facebook, google etc. which is all straight forward.

The issue is that we want to be able to setup for organizations the ability for them to have their users login using their ADFS server, or their azure ad (or any other oAuth 2 compliant server.)

Basically we use a subdomain xxx.yyy.com where xxx is unique to the organization. When they hit that subdomain we show them a button to login using their endpoint.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't find any documentation on how to set this up so that I can have multiple endpoints configured for wither oAuth over ADFS or oAuth over Azure (openconnect it looks like, can't tell if ADFS in Windows 2008 R2 supports openconnect, but it does support oAuth).

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to accomplish this? Do I need to setup a single app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() and then intercept based on the request some how for all of them? Or is there different rules for ADFS versus Azure so I have to use something else.

Any details would be fantastic. Even an inkling of where to go with this without having to use something like Auth0 would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/87279f6b1406978423618af1eb92f311d8b66cc6/source/Host.Configuration/IdentityServerExtension.cs).

You'll see a number of connections as a general guide (albeit in C#!).

ADFS in Server 2008 R2 has zero OpenID Connect / Ouath2 support. ADFS Server 2012 R2 has zero OpenID Connect / some OAuth2 support (Web API). ADFS Server 2016 is pretty similar to Azure AD - supports both.

Note that you need to support the hybrid OAuth profile.

You could use other protocols for ADFS e.g. WS Federation / SAML (using the OWIN libraries).

Or go the [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) route.

Comment: I tried the owin route but it appeared to take over the entire process and not work as a 3rd party provider. Would love to know how to get it to behave like Google/Facebook/openid in identity framework in a pop-up.